# jQuery select change show/hide div event

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I am trying to create a form which when the select element 'parcel' is selected it will show a div but when it is not selected I would like to hide the div. Here is my markup at the moment:

This is my HTML so far..

```
    <div class="row">    
    Type
        <select name="type" id="type" style="margin-left:57px; width:153px;">
                <option ame="l_letter" value="l_letter">Large Letter</option>
                <option name="letter" value="letter">Letter</option>
                <option name="parcel" value="parcel">Parcel</option>
        </select>                    
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_dim">
    Dimensions
        <input type="text" name="length" style="margin-left:12px;" class="dimension" placeholder="Length">
        <input type="text" name="width" class="dimension" placeholder="Width">
        <input type="text" name="height" class="dimension" placeholder="Height">
</div>
```

This is my jQuery so far..

```
  $(function() {
    $('#type').change(function(){
        $('#row_dim').hide(); 
        $("select[@name='parcel']:checked").val() == 'parcel').show();   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use following JQuery. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3pW9/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#row_dim').hide(); 
    $('#type').change(function(){
        if($('#type').val() == 'parcel') {
            $('#row_dim').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#row_dim').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if($("option[value='parcel']").is(":checked"))
   $('#row_dim').show();
```

Or even:

```
$(function() {
    $('#type').change(function(){
        $('#row_dim')[ ($("option[value='parcel']").is(":checked"))? "show" : "hide" ]();  
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3w5kD/

Comment: jQuery pseudo selectors are not the appropriate interface for checking form values.

Comment: @i_like_robots is it bad for performance? is it less readable? or just  not in fashion ?

Comment: The performance of pseudo-selectors is pretty poor - it's a lot of hoops to jump through - but selectors are really for traversing DOM objects and there are specific interfaces for checking form input values.

Comment: @i_like_robots i agree  , and i see all of them in the other answers.. so i give some not trivial alternative ;)

Comment: Here are a few loosely connected test cases comparing jQuery pseudo-selectors vs. alternative interfaces:

http://jsperf.com/eq-pseudo-selector-and-reduce-performance/2
http://jsperf.com/animated-pseudo-selector/3
http://jsperf.com/jquery-fastest-neq-filter

Comment: @i_like_robots thanks , good to know that `$items.filter(function(i)` (Custom filter) is actually faster than it looks

Answer (score 1):

change your jquery method to

```
$(function () { /* DOM ready */
    $("#type").change(function () {
        alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
        //hide the element you want to hide here with
        //("id").attr("display","block"); // to show
        //("id").attr("display","none"); // to hide
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorselector').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'red')
      {
        $("#divid").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#divid").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Do like this for every value
Also change the values... as per your parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try the below JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#type').change(function(){
        $('#row_dim').hide(); 
        if ($(this).val() == 'parcel')
        {
             $('#row_dim').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#type").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'parcel') $("#row_dim").show();
        else $("#row_dim").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function () {
     $('#row_dim').hide(); // this line you can avoid by adding #row_dim{display:none;} in your CSS
     $('#type').change(function () {
         $('#row_dim').hide();
         if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'parcel') {
             $('#row_dim').show();
         }
     });
 });
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz9AV/)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new but caching your jQuery collections will have a small perf boost

```
$(function() {

    var $typeSelector = $('#type');
    var $toggleArea = $('#row_dim');

    $typeSelector.change(function(){
        if ($typeSelector.val() === 'parcel') {
            $toggleArea.show(); 
        }
        else {
            $toggleArea.hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

And in vanilla JS for super speed:

```
(function() {

    var typeSelector = document.getElementById('type');
    var toggleArea = document.getElementById('row_dim');

    typeSelector.onchange = function() {
        toggleArea.style.display = typeSelector.value === 'parcel'
            ? 'block'
            : 'none';
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following jQuery-based snippet to have a `select`-element show a `div`-element that has an `id` that matches the `value` of the `option`-element while hiding the `div`s that do not match. Not sure that it's the best way, but it is a way.

```js
$('#sectionChooser').change(function(){
    var myID = $(this).val();
    $('.panel').each(function(){
        myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.panel {display: none;}
#one {display: block;}
```

```html
<select id="sectionChooser">
    <option value="one" selected>Thing One</option>
    <option value="two">Thing Two</option>
    <option value="three">Thing Three</option>
</select>

<div class="panel" id="one">
    <p>Thing One</p>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="two">
    <p>Thing Two</p>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="three">
    <p>Thing Three</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="form-control" >Pay Mode</label>
         <select id="pay_mode2" class="btn-default form-control ">
            <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
            <option value="cash" selected>Cash</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 cheque">
      <label class="form-control" >Cancelled</label>
         <select class="btn-default form-control ">
            <option value="no">No</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 cheque">
      <label class="form-control" >Instrument No</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
  $('#pay_mode2').change(function(){
  var myID = $(this).val();
 if(myID == 'cheque')
 {
  $('.cheque').each(function(){
      $(this).show();
  });
 }else{
  $('.cheque').each(function(){
      $(this).hide();
  });
 }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).