# If someone interacts with <select>, show div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<select>` drop down and I would like to make it so that when someone selects an option, a balloon-like div shows up next to it. It can be any option in the select box.

I wasn't really sure what to type in Google. I know some jQuery, but would it be something like `$('select option').click('#balloon').show();`? Or is there a "select" instead of "click"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select change show/hide div event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572401/jquery-select-change-show-hide-div-event)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.change()` to detect option change.Try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $('#balloon').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this with latest jquery:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
   $('#balloon').show();
});
```