# How can I show elements based on the selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Isn't there a better solution than the commented **if statement**?  I'm trying switch case but in this code, I can't hide the div so it's always existing which is wrong. I'm trying to show/hide elements depending on the selected option( it works with if statements but I think there's a cleaner way).

```html
 <div>
       <label>Privileges:</label>
       <select name="privileges" id="privileges" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
            <option id="all" value="all">All</option>
            <option id="custom" value="custom">Custom</option>
            <option id="test1" value="test1">test1</option>
            <option id="test2" value="test2">tst2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="resources" style=" display: none;">resources</div>
    <div class="test1" style=" display: none;">test1</div>
    <div class="test2" style=" display: none;">test2</div>
    <script>
    var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges');
    var select = this.value;

    **/*Privileges.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'custom') {
            $('.resources').show();
        }
        else $('.resources').hide();
    }); */**
    
    Privileges.change(function () {
    switch($(this).val()){
    case 'custom':
     $('.resources').show();
     break;
     case 'test1':
     $('.test1').show();
     break;
     case 'test2':
     $('.test2').show();
     break;
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975521/show-hide-div-based-on-select-option-jquery

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572401/jquery-select-change-show-hide-div-event

Comment: @isherwood the first link yes, but my idea was to use a switch case (which I think it won't work in this kind of problem).. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more succinct way to do this would be to put a common class on all the `div` elements you want to toggle so that you can easily hide them on `change`. In addition, add another class to them which matches the `value` of the `option` of they should be displayed when selected. From there you can easily build a selector to hide/show the content. Try this:

```js
var $privileges = jQuery('#privileges');

$privileges.on('change', e => {
  $('.content').hide().filter('.' + e.target.value).show();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Privileges:</label>
  <select name="privileges" id="privileges">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">tst2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="content custom">resources</div>
<div class="content test1">test1</div>
<div class="content test2">test2</div>
```

As an aside you should note that in order to follow best practices I moved the inline `style` attributes on the div to the stylesheet, and I also removed the `onclick` attribute you had on the `select` element. The latter should be attached unobtrusively using `addEventListener()`, if it's needed.

Comment: thank you so much Rory :) using the filter with commun class is a brilliant idea and I can't see a cleaner code than yours